# Eclipse Kepler Crash after startup with Message:-Java heap space

Tags: java, eclipse

I am getting below exception

```
An internal error occurred during: "Building workspace".
Java heap space
```

and then i am getting

```
An out of memory has occured. COnsult the "Running Eclipse" section of the read me file on preventing such kind of error in future..........................
DO you want to exit the workbench?
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity: did you ever "Consult the "Running Eclipse" section of the read me file"?

Comment: Yes @MarttiKäärik, I just checked that and it's there. :)

Comment: I actually couldn't see the readme file until I found this post. It's in readme/readme_eclipse.html.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

In your eclipse installation folder, find the **eclipse.ini** file and change

```
-Xms512m
-Xmx1024m
```

parameters according to your requirement.

Comment: For Mac users, you can locate eclipse.ini as below:  

On a Mac OS X system, you can find eclipse.ini by right-clicking (or Ctrl+click) on the Eclipse executable in Finder, choose Show Package Contents, and then locate eclipse.ini in the Eclipse folder under Contents.  

More details here:
https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini#-vm_value:_Mac_OS_X_Example

Answer (score 7):

You can use that faq
http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_increase_the_heap_size_available_to_Eclipse%3F

which indicates to modify the `eclipse.ini` file

the important ones

```
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
512m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vmargs
-Xms1024m
-Xmx2048m
-XX:+UseParallelGC
-XX:PermSize=512M
-XX:MaxPermSize=2048M
```

Comment: Why so ? i need to change it with another workspace same eclipse working fine even 10 project there why its not working with new workspace with two project only

Answer (score 2):

Just add this in your eclipse VM arguments.

```
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m -Xmx1024m
```

and restart the server.

Comment: I Did not add any server in eclipse yet

Comment: Are you running server application or consol application.

Comment: I am not running anything..Please see my question When i am starting eclipse and building is going on and i got message

Comment: This message from JVM because of JVM out of memory.
Are you running anything else using JVM that means using JAVA.

Comment: http://mirrors.download3k.com/token/0c4bd4b5f05074ce7b385ecfe1af83d4/cports.zip

download this and run it and then close all process which are all running using JAVA

Then restart you eclipse

Comment: I am not running any Java code i have two project in eclipse when i started eclipse i am getting this error after startup

Comment: An internal error occurred during: "Building workspace".
GC overhead limit exceeded

Answer (score 2):

Go to Eclise.ini file(C:\Program Files\eclipse-standard-kepler-SR2-win32-x86_64\eclipse\eclipse.ini) and open it with a Notepad to edit:
-Xms256m
-Xmx1024m (as per Requirement)

This will increase the heap size and overcomes the error.

PS:for Windows 7 and above,"Run as Administrator" can only Save the Change.