# An internal error occurred during: "Building workspace". Java heap space

Tags: java, eclipse

An internal error occurred during: "Building workspace".
Java heap space. How can I resolve this problem?

Previously I was using Eclipse Kepler for my application and now I upgraded to Eclipse Mars. And I did all necessary configurations. Also I upgraded from JAVA 7 to JAVA 8. After resolving all internal problems occurred and completed my configs, While cleaning & building work-space I faced this issue saying "An internal error occurred during: "Building workspace". Java heap space"

Comment: This problem occurs during building workspace

Comment: Try: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19178125/eclipse-kepler-crash-after-startup-with-message-java-heap-space

Comment: Please add more info to your problem such as the which specific error that you are seeing.

Thank you.

Comment: Previously I was using Eclipse Kepler for my application and now I upgraded to Eclipse Mars. And  I did all necessary configurations. Also I upgraded from JAVA 7 to JAVA 8. After resolving all internal problems occurred and completed my configs, While cleaning & building work-space I faced this issue saying "An internal error occurred during: "Building workspace". Java heap space" .